# Código no funciona a causa de un bucle que no actualiza la variable

Tags: c, codeblocks

tengo un código que dispone de una librería de palabras de esta forma :

`char palabras[500][27]`

de esta forma guardo 500 palabras de tamaño 27 cada una y puedo acceder a ellas fácilmente usando los primeros corchetes:

`printf("%s",palabras[i]);`

además tengo dos funciones que te devuelven el inicio y el final de la palabra que le metas como parámetro (estas son findepalabra e iniciopalabra) el problema aparece cuando intento introducir varias palabras en lugar de solo una usando un bucle for resulta que el valor de k no llega a incrementar en ningún momento.
**el trozo de código donde ocurre el error es el siguiente:**

```
for(k=0;k<=4;k++){
   printf("introduce la palabra: ");
   printf("%d\n",k);
   fflush(stdin);
   gets(palabras[k]);
strcpy(inicio,iniciopalabra(palabras[k]));
printf("%s\n",inicio);
   strcpy(fin,findepalabra(palabras[k]));
   printf("%s\n",fin);
   }
```

[image: imagen de lo que ocurre en el bucle]

tal parece que la variable no llega a actualizarse (a efectuar el k++) incluso si lo coloco en otro sitio hay momentos en los que el bucle avanza y otros en los que "se resetea el bucle" (k vuelve a valer 0).

he probado varias cosas y si lo que intento es simplemente introducir la palabra y ya está el programa funciona sin problemas, también funciona si uso una variable para almacenar el valor de la k (almacenar sin más, eso es lo que no entiendo)

```
for(k=0;k<=4;k++){
   printf("introduce la palabra: ");
   printf("%d\n",k);
   **i=k;**
   fflush(stdin);
   gets(palabras[k]);

strcpy(inicio,iniciopalabra(palabras[k]));
printf("%s\n",inicio);
   strcpy(fin,findepalabra(palabras[k]));
   printf("%s\n",fin);
   }
```

el código de arriba funciona y lo único que he cambiado es una linea en la que le asigno el valor de k a i, esto parece ser que sirve para actualizar la variable.
Por ahora el código hace lo que quiero pero quiero entender porqué no funcionaba correctamente si aparentemente no he cambiado nada.

En caso de ser necesario, el código de findepalabra e inicio palabra es este:

```
const char *findepalabra(char palabra[]){
int i;
int j=0;
int longitud;
char aux[3]="\0";
char *fin;
longitud=strlen(palabra);
if (longitud<=2){
    fin=palabra;
    return fin;
}
for(i=(longitud-2);i<=longitud;i++){
    aux[j]=palabra[i];
    j++;
}
fin=aux;
return fin;
}

const char *iniciopalabra(char palabra[]){
int i;
int j=0;
char aux[3]="\0";
char *inicio;
if(strlen(palabra)<=2){
    inicio=palabra;
    return inicio;
}

for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    aux[j]=palabra[i];
    j++;
}
inicio=aux;
return inicio;
}
```

repito que el código me funciona actualmente pero quiero saber el motivo por el cual no funcionaba anteriormente.

Comment: Has puesto mucho código ... y no me queda claro **que funciona** y que no.

Comment: Procura poner en tu título el problema presentado para que los y las lectoras se sientas atraidos en revisar tu pregunta, lee [ask]

Comment: La razón del porque no funcionaba es porque en el primer código no usabas un bucle para poder recorrer cada fila de la matriz... Si ese no es el motivo, debes agregar el código completo que no funcionaba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El único error que he encontrado en todo este galimatias:

```
const char *iniciopalabra(char palabra[]){
  int i;
  int j=0;
  char aux[3]="\0"; // <--- aux es variable local
  char *inicio;
  if(strlen(palabra)<=2){
    inicio=palabra;
    return inicio;
  }

  for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    aux[j]=palabra[i];
    j++;
  }
  inicio=aux; // <<--- puntero apunta a variable local
  return inicio; // <-- retornas puntero a variable local -> no valida
}
```

El problema es que cuando el programa abandona la función, la memoria de `aux` se libera y pasa a ser utilizada por otras variables.

La solución más rápida tal y como tienes el código es usar `static`:

```
static aux[3] = "";
```

Eso sí, nota entonces que cada llamada a `inicioPalabra` sobreescribirá el contenido de `aux`... y dado que devuelves punteros, si te los guardas verás que su contenido cambia mágicamente:

```
char* ptr1 = iniciopalabra("abcdef");
char* ptr2 = iniciopalabra("zzzzzz");

printf("%s %s", ptr1, ptr2);
```

Como no podía ser de otra forma, el error también lo encontramos en `findepalabra`

Comment: Alguna forma de devolver un string sin usar punteros? es posible que tengas razón y sea eso lo que está bugueando el bucle, pero las funciones parecen funcionar correctamente, solo fallan al meterlas dentro del for y es por que la variable k no se actualiza.   pd. el codigo para devolver una string lo saqué de aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929329/how-to-return-a-string-in-my-c-code  es podible que el fallo esté en ese codigo

Comment: @Daniel usa `std::string` en lugar de punteros a char

Comment: Por otro lado, fíjate que en la pregunta que indicas están devolviendo strings literales. Con esos strings no va a fallar porque se encuentran en una posición fija de la memoria del programa