# Bucle infinito sin motivo aparente

Tags: c, while

estoy haciendo un programa que te devuelve las dos primeras letras de una palabra y si la palabra tiene menos de dos letras te devuelve la palabra en sí, resulta que el código funciona correctamente pero no actualiza la variable **k** que controla el bucle a menos que la palabra introducida tenga menos de dos letras:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *iniciopalabra(char palabra[]){
int i;

static char inicio[3];
if(strlen(palabra)<=2){     //si la palabra mide menos de 2 letras la copia en inicio y la devuelve
    strcpy(inicio,palabra);
    return inicio;
}


for(i=0;i<2;i++){           //copia las dos primeras letras de palabra en incio
    inicio[i]=palabra[i];
}
return inicio;
}

int main()
{
   char inicio[2];
   char aux[27];
   int k=0;
   int i;


   while(k<4){               //lo que no funciona es este bucle, solo aumenta k si la palabra mide dos o menos letras y no entiendo porque

   printf("introduce la palabra: ");
   printf("%d\n",k);
   //i=k;                           //iguala i a k, esto arregla el bucle aunque desconozco por que (descomentarla para ver como lo arregla)
   fflush(stdin);
   gets(aux);                      
strcpy(inicio,iniciopalabra(aux));  
printf("%s\n",inicio);

   k++;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

a simple vista no parece haber ningún error ni ninguna interacción con **k**, he probado varias cosas y al parecer si igualas alguna variable a **k** (en este caso **i**) el bucle funciona correctamente. Usando un bucle for obtengo el mismo resultado.

adjunto algunas imagenes del funcionamiento:

[image: funcionamientodelcodigo]

se puede ver que el código iguala **k** a 0 al introducir una palabra de las de una letra.

hice la misma pregunta aqui: [Código no funciona a causa de un bucle que no actualiza la variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344752/c%c3%b3digo-no-funciona-a-causa-de-un-bucle-que-no-actualiza-la-variable) pero he decidido re formularla al encontrar el fallo para que sea mas clara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 char inicio[2];
```

En  C, las cadenas de caracteres terminan **siempre** con el caracter nulo `\0`, luego una cadena de 2 caracteres necesita un buffer de **3** elementos.

Lo que está sucediendo es que el sistema está ubicando la variable `k` justo después de `inicio`... al escribir 3 caracteres en `inicio` se sobreescribe el contenido de `k`.

```
| 00 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06
| inicio  |  k | otras variables ...
| XX | XX |  0 |                       <-- Inicio del programa
|0x70|0x61|  0 |                       <-- procesamos "palabra"
|0x70|0x61|  1 |                       <-- incrementamos k
|0x70|0x72|  0 |                       <-- procesamos "primera"
|0x70|0x61|  1 |                       <-- incrementamos k
|0x61|0x63|  0 |                       <-- procesamos "actualiza"
```

La solución pasa por incrementar en al menos una unidad, el tamaño del buffer `inicio`:

```
char inicio[3];
```

Comment: respondimos al mismo tiempo xD

Comment: @MrDave1999 eso estoy viendo... :)

Answer (score 4):

> > Bucle infinito sin motivo aparente

No es como tal un bucle infinito. Simplemente hay un posible [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) en esta línea:

```c
strcpy(inicio,iniciopalabra(aux));
```

Solo fijate en estas dos definiciones:

```c
char inicio[2]; //de la función main
static char inicio[3]; //de la función iniciopalabra
```

Como ambos arreglos no tienen el mismo tamaño, habrá sobrescritura de memoria.

Imagínate que el primer búfer (que básicamente es la cadena de origen) esta diseñado así:

```c
|0x20|0x21|
       \0
```

Y el segundo búfer (cadena de destino):

```c
|0x25|0x26|0x27|
   h    o   \0
```

Al copiar la cadena `ho` en el primer búfer, quedará de esta forma:

```c
|0x20|0x21|
   h    o
```

Pero, ¿a donde queda guardado el caracter nulo?

Pues la función `strcpy` lo estará escribiendo en la dirección `0x22`:

```c
|0x20|0x21|0x22|
   h    o    \0
```

Aquí viene el problema, que pasaría si la dirección `0x22` es donde se almacena los valores de la variable `k`. Pues habría sobrescritura de memoria, valdría cero! Y después se incrementa la variable con `k++` y por esa razón da uno.

**Solución:**

Añade un espacio adicional para el caracter nulo en esta definición:

```c
char inicio[2 + 1];
```

Comment: solucionado, pero por qué al añadir i=k se arregla el codigo?

Comment: @Daniel El desbordamiento de búfer puede pasar o no. Todo depende en que direcciones de memoria se alojen tus variables. Asumamos que ejecutamos tu programa y añadimos `i = k`, el programa puede funcionar si la variable `k` no se aloja en la dirección `0x22` (siguiendo el ejemplo de mi respuesta), sino, en `0x50`. Por lo tanto, no habría sobrescritura de memoria, pero obviamente te arriesgas a que sucede una falla de segmentación si es que se accede a una dirección que al programa no le pertenece.

Comment: @Daniel También debes fijarte que el `i = k` no arregla nada, porque la variable `i` en ningún momento le das una utilidad, le asignas un valor, pero no lo usas.

Comment: realmente eso es lo que me extraña mas, entiendo que se supone que no arregla nada pero, al hacer pruebas, mágicamente lo hacía, aunque a lo mejor era tema del IDE que al usar el valor de ```k``` para hacer ```i=k``` cambiase el lugar de la memoria donde se almazena ```k``` o algo por el estilo porque siendo sincero, codeblocks hace cosas raras de vez en cuando

Comment: @Daniel El IDE solo es de apoyo para poder programar en algún lenguaje, el no se encarga de gestionar la memoria del programa en tiempo de ejecución, es el Sistema Operativo. **Mira mi primer comentario** ahí te explico el porque.