# ¿Por qué me da problemas al comparar con la función strcmp?

Tags: c, comparaciones

Es mi primera vez que use esta funcion, la necesito para comparar o verificar que 2 datos ingresados por el usuario sean iguales en los 2 campos (cuando se registra y loguea)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main ()
{
    char User,Password,usu,contra;
    printf("Escribe tu nombre de usuario:");
    scanf("%s",&User);
    printf("Escribe una contrasena:");
    scanf("%s",&Password); //REGISTRO DE USUARIO
    system ("cls");
    printf("ingrese su nombre de usuario:");
    scanf("%s",&usu);
    printf("Ingrese su contrasena:");
    scanf("%s",&contra); //LOGUEO DE SESION
    if(strcmp(User,usu)==0)and(strcmp(Password,contra)==0) {
        printf("Inicio de sesion completado");
        return 0;

    }
    else 
    printf("Contrasena o Usuario Incorrectos Vuelva a intentarlo");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual seria el problema?

Comment: Todas las variables que has definido son de tipo `char` y solo pueden guardar un caracter. Debes declararlo como un array de caracteres. Ej: `char User[24];`. También me di cuenta que el programa está raro, porque el usuario se registra y se logea al mismo tiempo ¿?

Comment: Es un trabajo escolar de usar If, else y pense que este ejemplo seria el adecuado para demostrar sobre las condiciones a cumplirse para llegar al resultado, gracias intentare lo que dijiste

Comment: Te he dado una respuesta. Espero te sirva!

Answer (score 1):

> > ¿Por qué me da problemas al comparar con la función strcmp?

Porque los parámetros de la función [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) son de tipo `const char*` y lo que estás pasando es un argumento de tipo `char`.

Las variables que tengan el tipo de dato `char` solo podrán guardar un caracter. Entonces en ningún momento podrás comparar cadenas si la variable es de tipo `char`.

Otro error es la forma como especificas el formato en la función `scanf`:

```c
scanf("%s",&User);
```

La función `scanf` leerá una cadena y no únicamente un caracter y esto ocasionará que la función escriba en una zona de memoria que no le pertenece al programa (a esto se denomina [falla de segmentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso)) o también puede sobrescribir la propia memoria del programa (mirar este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/347392/bucle-infinito-sin-motivo-aparente/347407#347407)).

**Solución:** Debes definir un array de caracteres en vez de un variable de tipo `char`:

```c
int main ()
{
    char User[24], Password[24], usu[24], contra[24];
    printf("Escribe tu nombre de usuario:");
    scanf("%s", User);
    printf("Escribe una contrasena:");
    scanf("%s", Password); //REGISTRO DE USUARIO
    system ("cls");
    printf("ingrese su nombre de usuario:");
    scanf("%s", usu);
    printf("Ingrese su contrasena:");
    scanf("%s", contra); //LOGUEO DE SESION
    if(strcmp(User,usu)==0) && (strcmp(Password,contra)==0) {
        printf("Inicio de sesion completado");
        //Este return 0; es innecesario
        return 0;

    }
    else 
     printf("Contrasena o Usuario Incorrectos Vuelva a intentarlo");
    return 0;

}
```

**Nota:** En cada invocación de la función `scanf` quité el ampersand(`&`) ya que es innecesario.

Ejemplo:

```c
printf("%p = %p", &User, User);
```

Dan el mismo resultado, que vendría ser la dirección base del array. Por lo tanto, no necesitas usar este operador cuando el identificador es definido como array.