# IF, ELSE el compilador me pide que ponga un ; despues de mi condicion de IF pero al momento de ponerlo Else deja de funcionar

Tags: c, condiciones

el problema esta que me pide un ; despues de mi condicion de IF lo que hace que else me cause problemas diciendo no hay un IF previo para que else funcione, Es un trabajo escolar por si ven raro el codigo sobre porque se loguea y registra de seguido

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    int main ()
    {
        char User,Password,usu,contra;
        printf("Escribe tu nombre de usuario:");
        scanf("%s",&User);
        printf("Escribe una contrasena:");
        scanf("%s",&Password); //REGISTRO DE USUARIO
        system ("cls");
        printf("ingrese su nombre de usuario:");
        scanf("%s",&usu);
        printf("Ingrese su contrasena:");
        scanf("%s",&contra); //LOGUEO DE SESION
        if(strcmp(User,usu)==0)and(strcmp(Password,contra)==0) {
            printf("Inicio de sesion completado");
            return 0;

        }
        else 
        printf("Contrasena o Usuario Incorrectos Vuelva a intentarlo");
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: No debes de crear otra pregunta. Esto ya está duplicado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350092/problemas-para-usar-strcmp-en-un-ejercicio-de-registro-y-logue-de-usuario-c

Answer (score 1):

Plagado de errores, bien, tranquilo, el operador lógico **and** se escribe como **&&** en c. Esto debería ser suficiente para eliminar tu error. Sin embargo existen otros errores. El mas serio sería declarar un string o cadena de caracteres como un char, o caracter individual. Debes tener clara la diferencia entre char y char*, echa un vistazo a la definición de la función **srtcmp()** y mira el tipo de sus argumentos

Answer (score 1):

El if debe llevar paréntesis rodeando toda la condición:

```
    if ((strcmp(User,usu)==0)&&(strcmp(Password,contra)==0)) {
```

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas cerrar el else con unos paréntesis, al igual que haces con el if:

```
else {
        printf("Contrasena o Usuario Incorrectos Vuelva a intentarlo");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esto no es cierto, si solo hay una declaración no es necesario el usa de paréntesis, return 0 no pertenece a la clausura else.

Comment: Lo que dices tampoco es cierto @MARS . Para empezar no son paréntesis (`()`) si no llaves (`{}`) y para acabar el uso de llaves es opcional si la cláusula tiene una única instrucción, no una única declaración.