# ¿Qué tengo mal para realizar una búsqueda secuencial en una matriz con valores dados por el usuario?

Tags: array, c, bucle-for, condiciones, while

Debo de hacer un array pidiendo al usuario el número de elementos que debe tener, rellenar el array con números digitados por el mismo usuario, luego pedir al usuario cualquier número , y hacer una búsqueda secuencial para indicar si ese elemento existe o no, también entregar la posición en la que se encuentra el numero antes indicado por el usuario.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define tam 50
int main()
{
int matriz1[tam][tam],filas,columnas,i,j,x,dato;
char band= 'F';


printf("\t\t\t\tSUMA DE MATRICES\n\n");
printf("digite la cantidad de filas\n");
scanf("%i",&filas);
printf("digite la cantidad de columnas\n");
scanf("%i",&columnas);

printf("\n\n");
for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
    for(j=0;j<columnas;j++){
    printf("Digite un numero matriz[%i][%i]",i+1,j+1);
    scanf("%i",&matriz1[i][j]); 
    }

}
printf("\n\n");
for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
    for(j=0;j<columnas;j++){
        printf("%i ",matriz1[i][j]);    
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t\tBUSQUEDA SECUENCIAL\n\n");
printf("Digite el numero que quiere buscar\n");
scanf("%i",&dato);

x=0;
while((band=='F')&&(x<tam)){
    if(matriz1[x]==dato){
    band = 'V';
    }
x++;    
}
if(band=='F'){
    printf("El numero no se encontro");}

else if (band=='V'){
printf("El numero fue encontrado, posicion %i",x-1);
}
getch();

 return 0;}
```

Comment: array o mariz? vos estas buscando en un array, no en una matriz.. (que supongo sabes usar por el codigo para llenarla)

Answer (score 1):

> > ¿Qué tengo mal para realizar una búsqueda secuencial en una matriz con valores dados por el usuario?

El problema radica en esta línea:

```c
if(matriz1[x]==dato)
```

Siempre estarás comparando el valor que tenga la variable `dato` con cada elemento de la primera columna de la matriz.

Así que ese código solo funcionará si el dato que se quiere encontrar está en la primera columna, de lo contrario, es como si no estuviera en la matriz.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
int main(void)
{
    int matriz1[2][2] = 
    {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 5}
    };
    printf("%d, %d\n", matriz1[0], matriz1[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado por pantalla:

```c
1, 3
```

Como verás, esta expresión: `matriz[0]` **siempre** dará el primer elemento de cada fila.

Así que la forma como debes buscar el elemento en la matriz, es usando un bucle anidado:

```c
for(int i = 0; band == 'F' && i < filas; i++) //Para recorrer las filas
{
    for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)//Para recorrer las columnas
    {
        if(matriz1[i][j] == dato)
        {
            band = 'V';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Observación:**

El total de filas y columnas son `50` (pues lo defines con `#define tam 50`). Si el usuario ingresa por teclado un número que sobrepase este tamaño, ocurrirá un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) (mirar este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/347392/bucle-infinito-sin-motivo-aparente/347407#347407)) cuando recorras la matriz a través de un bucle y esto ocasiona una [falla de segmentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso) si tratas de acceder a un espacio de memoria que no le pertenece al programa o incluso sobrescribir la propia memoria del programa

**Dos posibles soluciones:**

**1-.** Limitar la entrada al usuario, es decir, que solo pueda ingresar como tamaño hasta `50`.

**2-.** Usar una [matriz dinámica](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Matrices_Dinamicas), de este modo, el número de filas y columnas de la matriz se conocerán en tiempo de ejecución.